# http-server : how to set the root directory of my server?

Tags: node.js, makefile, httpserver

I run a server via node's [http-server module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server#available-options). Trouble is, it displays the working directory `/document/js/` :

```
# /document/js/server.makefile
node ../node_modules/.bin/forever ../node_modules/.bin/http-server --cors &
# localhost:8080 shows content of /document/js/
```

I actually want my server to show the content of `/document`.

**How to set the root folder of my server (`/document/js/server.makefile`) so localhost:8080 displays the content of `/document/` ?**

Answer (score 0):

The http-server docs [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server#usage) states that you can pass in a path before your options. So in your case, you might want to try something like:

```
hs /document [your_options]
```

Add `-o` to open your browser after starting your server.